# sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified (MAC)

Tags: python, macos, permissions, sudo, sudoers

I'm running an anaconda program with sudo:

```
sudo /Users/me/anaconda3/bin/python myScript.py
```

And I'm getting the error:

```
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
```

Eventhough I edited my sudoers file:

```
# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL) ALL
my_user ALL=(ALL) ALL
my_user ALL = NOPASSWD: /Users/orenkobo/anaconda3/bin/python
my_user ALL = NOPASSWD: ALL
my_user ALL = (ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
%admin  ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

What can be the reason?
Thanks!